# Merge multiple JSF projects

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have 3 JSF projects (let's say A, B, C) each having same database, server.  I want to merge projects A, B into one and make it available over internet, similarly merge project A, C into one and make it available over intranet.

Intranet website will need an authentication layer, I will probably add JDBCRealm authentication.

What is the best procedure to do this, I want the code to be reusable.  Do I need to use EJB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question. But if you just want advice on how to manage projects and dependencies between them I would take a look at maven. 
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

I have a setup I really like, it's basic but I will describe it anyway:

**myproject-webapp**: This module / project has JSF facelets, controllers, and other things specific for the web portal. It is the topmost project in terms of dependencies.

**myproject**: This module has the domain classes and the specific business logic.

Whenever I start a new project it is composite of those two parts. Now anytime I write some domain or business logic code that other projects can benefit from I put that code in it's own module called "core".

Respectively any time I write some jsf or web aware code that could (and should) be unspecific I make that generic as well and put it in "web-util".

So anytime I create a new project first thing I do is declare dependencies to "core" and "web-util". This makes each project really slim code-wise and straight to the point. Boilerplate code such as as generic dao, custom converters, custom interceptors/producers/events and whatnot is immediately available.

Answer (score 0):

- Separate out all your concerns, that is authentication and other environment specific information (a,b, &c)

  - Create deployment scripts that build target specific or deploy target environment specific.
  - Note there is a difference in the above ( user whichever is safest).